# Alphabetical Order for all Localizable Strings

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, localization

i've a simple table cell with some names in alphabetical order in English.
I managed to localized all in some other language and all works fine.
the question is : There is a method or command to put the localized names in other languages in alphabetical order?

```
import UIKit

var animals = [“A1”, “A2”, “A3”, “A4”, “A5”];

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return animals.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellController;
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura-Bold", size: 18);
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black;
        cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString(animals[indexPath.row], comment: "");
        cell.smallBird.image = UIImage(named: animals[indexPath.row] + ".png");
        return cell
    }
}
```

Localizable strings

```
/* Animals (EN) */

“A1" = “Cat”;
“A2" = “Dog”;
“A3" = “Owl”;
“A4" = “Leon”;
“A5" = “Tiger”;
```

Comment: FYI - You don't need semicolons at the end of lines in Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy But OP is using a .strings file for localizing strings, and in that case you do need a semicolon.

Comment: @Xcoder I'm talking about the Swift code, not the strings file.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't see his Swift code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ordering them by the keys at the moment, not the values.

Since you need the keys for the images and the value for the labels, and you want to sort the rows by the values, you need more than just the array of keys.

The following creates an array of tuples of keys and localized names, sorted by the localized name.

```
let animals = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"].map { ($0, NSLocalizedString($0, comment: "")) }.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }
```

Then update `cellForRowAt`:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = animals[indexPath.row].1
cell.smallBird.image = UIImage(named: animals[indexPath.row].0)
```

You do not need to add the ".png" when using `UIImage(named:)`.